# Grammaticality of "Had I got the time"

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

I would like to say, "If I had got more time, I could have done it a lot better in a more efficient and short way."

But, how do I say that without having to use 'if'.

Comment: "If I had gotten more time" and "Had I had the time" would be the correct forms of the expressions you're trying to use. The former is more "active", so to speak, but I'll let someone else elaborate on the grammatical why's.

Answer (score 8):

**Had I had the time** is another way of saying it without "if".  It is the inversion form of the third conditional, and it is a more formal way to say something.  We can use the inversion form for all the conditionals:

*Conditional type 1:* If he refuses, let me know.
*Inversion:* **Should** he refuse, let me know.

*Conditional type 2:* If she were here, you would see it.
*Inversion:* **Were** she here, you would see it.

*Conditional type 3:* If you had been here, I'd have seen you.
*Inversion:* **Had** you **been** here, I'd have seen you.

Comment: When should one go with the inversion form?

Comment: I think you'll find all the answers here: [Inversion](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/inversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

> Given more time, the results would have been better."

You can add "more efficient" or other terms with/in place of "better" if you want to.